# Migrating from Groovy to Kotlin, upgrading Gradle versions too

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

Hello Gradle experts!,

I want to migrate a complicated multi-module with and old Gradle version (4.7) to the latest Gradle. I would like to be able to test the new build environment by also moving to Kotlin (Existing version is Groovy).

So my questions are:

- It is possible to have side by side Kotlin scripts with Gradle scripts, and let old Gradle use the Groovy scripts by default? ( I didn’t saw this approach documented here: [Migrating build logic from Groovy to Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html))
- Or I should byte the bullet first by migrating Gradle from 4.7 to 7.2, while keep using Groovy? If so, any recommendations while doing this refactoring?

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you me need to explain this into more detail.

–Jose

Comment: >Note that you can mix Groovy DSL build scripts with Kotlin DSL ones, i.e. a Kotlin DSL build script can apply a Groovy DSL one and each project in a multi-project build can use either one.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:interoperability

Comment: Probably it will be easier to migrate from 4.7 to 7.2 if you migrate to Kotlin first (as a strongly-typed language it has better IDE support) and use `-all` Gradle distribution (`gradle wrapper --gradle-version XXX --distribution-type all`)

Comment: Hello Михаил, thanks a lot. I'm going to try that and see how it goes, looks like I will need a lot of help from the IDE,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating to Kotlin seems to be the right path, then an upgrade to a newer version of Gradle will be easier.